Deeplink is not working in mobile chrome in xamarin forms
I am working in xamarin forms where I have to use Deeplink for android. Deeplink is working from any messanger app (skype,whatsapp,etc) but failed in mobile any browser.
below is my code.
I have publish javasript code deeplink.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Veepee App</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--<button id="checkApp">Check if Veepee App is Installed</button>-->
<script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        //document.getElementById('checkApp').addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var pageName = urlParams.get('page'); // Replace with the actual page name you want to pass
 
            // Function to detect if the device is Android
            function isAndroid() {
                return /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
            }
 
            // Function to detect if the device is iOS
            function isIOS() {
                return /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
            }
 
            if (isAndroid()) {
                // Android-specific code
                var appPackageName = 'com.companyname.veepee';
                var appLink = 'intent://wholesale.veepeeonline.com/'+ pageName +'/#Intent;scheme=http;package=' + appPackageName + ';end';
 
                // Attempt to open the app
                window.location = appLink;
 
                // Fallback to Play Store if the app is not installed
                setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('App is not installed.');
                    window.location.href = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=' + appPackageName;
                }, 2000);
            } else if (isIOS()) {
                // iOS-specific code
                var appLink = 'veepeedomain://veepeedomain/'+ pageName ;
 
                // Attempt to open the app
                window.location = appLink;
 
                // Fallback to App Store if the app is not installed
                setTimeout(function() {
                    alert('App is not installed.');
                    window.location.href = 'https://apps.apple.com/in/app/veepee-international/id6450380169';
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                alert('Unsupported device.');
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>

assetlinks.json
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.companyname.veepee",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "debug sha....",  
        "release sha..."
      ]
    }
  }
]

AndroidMenifest.xml
  <activity android:name="SplashActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop">

</activity>

MainActivity.cs
 [Activity(Label = "Veepee", Icon = "@drawable/logo", Exported = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
 [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
               DataScheme = "http",
               DataHost = "wholesale.veepeeonline.com",
               DataPathPrefix = "/",
               AutoVerify = true,
               Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

 [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
               DataScheme = "https",
               DataHost = "wholesale.veepeeonline.com",
               DataPathPrefix = "/",
               AutoVerify = true,
               Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

App.xaml.cs
protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{
base.OnAppLinkRequestReceived(uri);
      if (uri.Host.ToLower() == "wholesale.veepeeonline.com" && uri.Segments != null && uri.Segments.Length == 2)
      {
          var queryParams = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
          string name = queryParams["page"];
          //string action = uri.Segments[1].Replace("/", "");
          string action = name;
          bool isActionParamsValid = long.TryParse(uri.Segments[1], out long productId);
          Constants.PageNameFromURL = action;
          Constants.OpenFromURL = true;
          //if (action.ToLower() == "pendingreportview")
          //{
          //}
      }
  }

Please give me solution
Thanks in advance
